# How do I set query limit in template 'for post in user.post_set.all' ? (without using views)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to basically do something like this:

```
{% for post in user.post_set.all[:3] %}
```

But I do not know how to go about this. At the moment it is getting all the posts by the user, which is not what I want. Any way to do this without using views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) django template filter, although it is preferred that you do these calculations in your `views`

Example:

```
{% for post in user.post_set.all|slice:":3" %}
```

Comment: Is it by chance faster/safer to do it in the views?

Comment: @Mike i wouldnt say faster/safer, but it follows the principal of separation of concerns. Its best to do all of the query calculations in views.py, and then focus on displaying them in the html.